# ShareKit/Twitter memory leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter, sharekit

I've got a problem - I'm using ShareKit 2.0, and while I'm testing on iOs 5.0.1 I get some memory leaks when I'm trying to share on Twitter. To be exact, at the moment when native ios5 twitter window pops-up, and when i hit "send". The problem seems to be in TWSession. When I'm testing on iOS 4.3, and using custom sharekit twitter window there are no leaks. Any idea on how to fix it? Will this be an issue on the approval process? I'm not using ARC btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of an app being rejected for a small memory leak. Also, unless the whole point of your app is to send tweets, users are unlikely to send enough tweets to make a big difference (annoying as any leak is).

Comment: Oh, good to know. I thought that any memory leak is a reason for rejection. Sending tweets is just an additional feature in my app.

Comment: Still worth trying to track down the leak if you can, but I released an app with the older ShareKit, which has all sorts of Analyzer warnings about memory management. I can't remember if I looked for leaks at runtime, but it's such a secondary feature for me as well that I just didn't worry much.

Answer (score 0):

What I have also found the codes caused leaks are as the followings:

Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
**NSMallocBlock**,1 0xf641c50   32 Bytes    Twitter -[TWInFlightSessionCallInfo setRemoteCall:]
TWInFlightSessionCallInfo,1 0xf676380   16 Bytes    Twitter -[TWSession emptyCallInfo]
Malloc 16 Bytes,1   0xf6457c0   16 Bytes    Twitter -[TWSession recordAndIssueCallInfo:]
Malloc 128 Bytes,2  < multiple >    256 Bytes   libdispatch.dylib   dispatch_queue_create$VARIANT$up
NSLock,1    0xf64b450   64 Bytes    Twitter -[TWSession init]
TWSession,1 0xf62c3e0   32 Bytes    Twitter -[TWTweetComposeViewController session]
NSMutableArray,1    0x2c8540    32 Bytes    Twitter -[TWSession init]
**NSMallocBlock**,1 0x1084ebb0  32 Bytes    Twitter -[TWInFlightSessionCallInfo setRemoteCall:]